# HTML and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

So im doing this project. Im creating a calendar planner website that allows users to register, login and create their own plans, events and deadlines. (like google calendar).

I have created my register and login page and stored this data in a database using phpmyadmin. For now I only have a user table. My issue is I cant get my head around on how i should approach the calendar database and how everything will tie in together.

My initial approach is...

- Users - will have their unique ID which is the primary key.
- The calendar database will have an ID that will have a relationship with the user ID.
- The calendar will have date, event ID, notes? possible even more data types.
- When the user logs in, the php/html will call the database and populate the calendar with the appropriate data.

For my limited understanding of databases am I on the right track?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

**First**

As pointed by @Federico klez Culloca, you should take a look at "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)".

**Secondly**

There's a lot of things to consider when designing a database structure from scrath, for once please stop calling 'databases' when you acctually mean 'tables', one 'table' for users, one for calenders, etc..

From a basic understanding, here's a list of key points to consider:

- Yes, the user ID should in fact be the primary key of the users table;
- The calendar table must also have an ID as a primary key;
- Consider making the main calendar table a relational table only, meaning that all fields have relation IDs and no actual data itself, due to the complexity of the project itself i recommend you split everything to is own table, for example on table for the calendar data, one for event data, etc.., u can relate them all with the IDs.

From here brings the questions, does a user have one calendar? Or multiple? Does one calendar have one note? Or multiple? Should I store HTML on the database?

This way you can scetch a model with called pivot tables, if the relations are one-to-many, or even many-to-many.

**Conclusion**

Do more reserach, study relationship models so you can get a better understanding of the model. After you have proper code then come to stackOverflow with a proper description of the problem, instead of jumping here from the start.

Best Regards.